# How do I read .ETL files in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, etl

How do I read .ETL files in .Net? I want to see my etl file in a list view but I cant parse the contents of the file as it isnt ascii.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never mind i figured it out using various google searches. this is how I did it:

```
    //Init
    System.Diagnostics.Process worker = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    //Start logging
    worker.StartInfo.FileName="logman";
    worker.StartInfo.Arguments="start MyTcpipLog -p Microsoft-Windows-TCPIP -ets";
    worker.Start();
    worker.WaitForExit();
    //Do nothing for 30 seconds
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    while(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).Seconds<5){}
    //Stop logging
    worker.StartInfo.FileName="logman";
    worker.StartInfo.Arguments="stop MyTcpipLog -ets";
    worker.Start();
    worker.WaitForExit();
    //Convert .etl to .csv
    worker.StartInfo.FileName="tracerpt";
    worker.StartInfo.Arguments = "\""+System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)+"\\MyTcpipLog.etl\" -o \""+System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)+"\\MyTcpipLog.csv\"";
    worker.Start();
    worker.WaitForExit();
    //Load CSV into memory
    // create reader & open file
    System.IO.TextReader tr = new System.IO.StreamReader("MyTcpipLog.csv");
    string data = tr.ReadToEnd();
    tr.Close();
    //Delete CSV
    System.IO.File.Delete("MyTcpipLog.etl");
    System.IO.File.Delete("MyTcpipLog.csv");
```

Comment: will accept this as my answer when SO lets me (says i need to wait 2 days)

Comment: by the way its not actually csv, looks more like xml, which is better :D

Comment: So what he basically does here is `tracerpt <yourfile.etl> -o <yourcsv.csv>`

Answer (score 3):

You could probably use P/Invoke and the WinAPI OpenTrace and ProcessTrace functions. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364087%28VS.85%29.aspx) for some sample code in C.

Comment: P/Invoke allows you to call Win32 functions from .NET code. The samples would show which functions you'd need to call...